# Standalone WLST for both WebLogic 8.1 and 9.2?

Tags: scripting, weblogic

I'm writing a simple script to facilitate changing JDBC connection URLs in several WL environments, among these both v8.1 and v9.2.

I want to create a standalone script, outside of any WL installation, just including wlst.jar/jython.jar/weblogic.jar, that will work both on WL 8.1 and 9.2 (obviously by referencing different MBeans).

Now, this works OK for WL 8.1. I copy weblogic.jar from the server, and have managed to get ahold of both wlst.jar and jython.jar (wasn't easy, Oracle doesn't host them anymore). Also I need to make sure to locally run under the same JRE as the server (WL8.1 runs on Java 1.4.2).

But if I try to connect to WL 9.2 from this setup, I get a NullPointerException when trying to access any MBean (probably because I'm running on JRE 1.4.2 and WL 9.2 uses 1.5.0).

Also, I am unable to create a standalone environment for WL 9.2. If I copy weblogic.jar from 9.2 and run WLST like so:

```
java -cp "wlst.jar:jython.jar:weblogic-92.jar" weblogic.WLST
```

I get a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/management/configuration/RepositoryMBean` error. I can't find this class in `weblogic92/server/lib`, but it **IS** inside weblogic.jar from WL 8.1.

So I'm really losing my patience here...

Is there any way to create a standalone WLST client that can connect to any version of WebLogic (8.1 & 9.2 in the meantime)?

I really wouldn't want to have to ssh into the WL environment to run my WLST script...

Any ideas/suggestions are welcome.

Thanks,

Ivan

Answer (score 1):

I think there are different versions of WLST, one for 1.4 and a different one for 1.5. When you try invoking the 1.5 version, you cannot use java 1.4.

Your best bet is to have a wrapper script that launches the separate WLST sessions and then returns the results uniformly.

Answer (score 0):

From WebLogic 9.X onwards, WLST.jar file is shipped as a part of the weblogic.jar file present in BEA_HOME/weblogic922/server/lib directory.

You can just run the WLST as below as below.

**java -cp C:\bea103\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\weblogic.jar weblogic.WLST**

Else, you can run the **setDomainEnv** script to set the classpath and then run as  below.

**java weblogic.WLST**

For more WLST Scripts you can refer the link below.

http://weblogic-wonders.com/weblogic/wlst/

Cheers,
Anandraj
http://weblogic-wonders.com

Comment: This works if I run WLST from a different directory on a server with WebLogic installed. However, I want to create a standalone WLST environment/script that would work outside of any WebLogic installation. If I copy weblogic.jar to another machine, I get the following error: `Problem invoking WLST - java.lang.RuntimeException: error in finding weblogic.Home`. If I set weblogic.home (-Dweblogic.home="..\\..\\"), then I get: `Problem invoking WLST - java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find the OffLine WLST class`.